# 7zip cmd line write a file name with underscores

Tags: cmd, 7zip

this seems like a simple one but I can't find it anywhere!

I want to zip up a file with this command:

```
@"a -tzip -mx0 -v500m -mmt -- C:\Greg_Folder\zippedPackage.zip D:\tmp\failedImages";
```

This basically means that I'd like to zip up the folder "D:\tmp\failedImages" and move it to "C:\Greg_Folder\zippedPackage.zip"

THE PROBLEM:  I want to zip to the "Greg_Folder" and not 'Greg Folder"... but underscores seem to be translated to spaces in the cmd line.  So I need a way to say that I want the underscores to be treated literally as part of the directory name.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just compressed some folder on my drive using your command without the @ and the quotes.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -mx0 -v500m -mmt -- C:\Greg_Folder\zippedPackage.zip K:\devkitPro\devkitARM\arm-eabi
```

I just did not put the "@" sign which is for some other option (and your bug seems to be a strange side-effect), and it even created the "Greg_Folder" directory and the .zip.001 file inside.